# Get option of a select when the option choice changes

Tags: php, jquery

I Have a select list, each option contains a category ($k[3]) in its id.

```
    <select name="page_from_link" class="my_select_list" >
                <OPTION VALUE="" >With:</OPTION>                
            <?php foreach($pages_created as $k) { 
                $i=0; ?>                        
                <OPTION id="<?php $i."-".$k[3]; ?>" class="pages_created" VALUE="<?php echo $k[0]; ?>" ><?php echo $k[1]; ?></OPTION>           
            <?php } ?>  
    </select>
```

I have another select list with all options hidden depending on the precedent select category :
        
        AS:
        $v) { ?>
        " >

my jquery script doesn't work, how would you have done that ?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){         

        $(".my_select_list").change(function(){
            var array = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id').split('-');
            var cat = array[1];

            alert("cat");

            $("#cat_"+cat).show();
            $(".pages_created_option:not(#cat_"+cat).hide();

        return false;       
        });
    });
```

Comment: I think you can't mix `this` and `> option` ! Please try `$(this).find("option").attr('id').split('-');`

Comment: Dosen't work to get the option of a select :s

Answer (score 1):

`$(this > option).attr(...` => `$(this).find('option:selected').attr (...`

`alert("cat");` => `alert(cat);`

`$("#cat_"+cat+")").show();` => `$("#cat_"+cat).show();`

you should consider using firebug or chrome internal development tools (on F12).

on a side note, you might like to use optgroup instead of a dummy option:

```
<select name="page_from_link" class="my_select_list" >
    <OPTGROUP label="With:">
        <?php foreach($pages_created as $k) { 
            $i=0; ?>                        
            <OPTION id="<?php $i."-".$k[3]; ?>" class="pages_created" VALUE="<?php echo $k[0]; ?>" ><?php echo $k[1]; ?></OPTION>           
        <?php } ?>  
    </OPTGROUP>    
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections but the line var array = $(this).find('option').attr('id').split('-'); seems not to work, i can't get the id option with find('option'). it's weird. do there is another way ?

Comment: huh, true sorry: use `$(this).find('option:selected')` (or `$('option:selected', this)`)!!! on a side note you want to uses something like `<OPTION id="option<?php $i."-".$k[3]; ?>`, as IDs starting with numbers are not valid in HTML

Comment: Thanks a lot ! but my var cat is undefined is the alert frame although $k[3] exists when I print_r() the array $page_created of the foreeach.

Comment: which browser are you using? wha does the option show if you inspect it? Anyway, it works [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkDYt/)

Answer (score 0):

you could use either a php script, or a js script with the data encoded, holding the innerHTML and that changes the innerHTML of the parent object (such as a div) depending on what you selected in the previous select box.

Answer (score 0):

add this in the head for javascript

```
function showsel()
{if(document.getElementById('parentid').value=="id of the option that will triger the shild ")
    {document.getElementById('shild id').style.display="inline";}

else {document.getElementById('shild id').style.display="none";}
}
```

Then add  for the shild

```
div id="shild id" style="display:none"
```

and to the parent

```
div id="parent id" onchange"showsel()"
```